# Select2 pre selected seperated with comma from database

Tags: html, jquery, dropdown, jquery-select2, html-select

i am trying to display preselected values obtained from database seperated with comma but unable to do so, currently my code is working fine with one selection but for multiple selection i don't know how to put comma between values.
Lets suppose if data in database is (foo,moo),Here is the syntax of jquery which i am using

```
$('.multi_select').select2().val(['<?php echo $categories; ?>']).trigger('change')
```

This display (['foo,moo'])
i am trying to put single quote mark after foo and then again single quote mark before starting moo. so that resulting display should be (['foo','moo'])
i am strugling from 2 days but unable to get solution.Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if `'<?php echo $categories; ?>'`  = 'foo,moo,...,..', for example, you have to split the string:

```
var d0 = ['<?php echo $categories; ?>'];
var d1 = d0[0].split(",");
$('.multi_select').select2().val(d1).trigger('change');
```

or

```
var d0 = '<?php echo $categories; ?>';
var d1 = d0.split(",");
$('.multi_select').select2().val(d1).trigger('change');
```

i am not expert in php, may be this works:

```
var d0 = '<?php echo $categories; ?>'.split(",");
$('.multi_select').select2().val(d0).trigger('change');
```

or

```
$('.multi_select').select2().val('<?php echo $categories; ?>'.split(",")).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions but I have tried all above methods but not working. As , is already available in cell, i want single quote ' before starting comma.

Comment: are you sure about the the content, what is the value of `'<?php echo $categories; ?>'` ?, so you trap the value in d0? display d0, are you sure to not have twice single quote?

Comment: i dont see why is not functional,......to use this functionality, the values have to exist in the dropdown list..

Comment: Value of <?php echo $categories; ?> is foo,moo and i want it should display like 'foo','moo' so this is the syntax to display pre selected values from drop down

Comment: and value of d0?  because it seems your php value is not a string?